# Error while closing the UIDocumentPicker

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickervc

I am trying to initiate DocumentPicker in my app. I have declared:

```
var documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController = 
   UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: 
    ["public.text"], in: UIDocumentPickerMode.open)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = 
   UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
    self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and for picked document:

```
func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL url: NSURL) {

    if controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.exportToService {

    //do some stuff
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However i am doing something wrong here. Whenever i choose a file or close the window I keep getting this error:

> viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={Terminated=disconnect method}.

I have tried looking for a solution but i couldn't find anything useful.

EDIT: I have included a couple of print("test") into the documentPicker function to see if it is working. However i get 0 response from the console. Maybe I have implemented documentPicker in a bad way?

Comment: Are you testing in real device ?

Comment: Both real iPhone and simulator.

Comment: Did you turn on the iCloud Documents capabilities? [Document Picker](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Yes i did turn it on.

Comment: Did you proof in real device with Testflight or debug? Because some times DocumentsPicker doesn't work on debug.

Answer (score 2):

I, too, get this error message but not all the time.

I noticed the documentPicker is deprecated. Try this:

```
func documentPicker(controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAtURL urls: [URL]) {

    if controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.exportToService {

    //do some stuff
    }

}
```

There's no need to have the dismiss statement. The picker is closed automatically.

Try this and see if it works.